# I am trying to map a json string to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I am using this string as a parameter 
"{'totalCount':'1','ID':'1029','IP':'10.0.0.1'}"

And it should return a dictionary that will have the following values

`result[“totalCount”]`: value will be '1'

`result[“ID”]`: value will be '1029'

`result[“IP”]`: value will be '10.0.0.1'

What is wrong with my code?

```
import json
example_string = "{'totalCount':'1','ID':'1029', 'IP':'10.0.0.1'}"
result = json.loads(example_string)

print(result["'totalCount','ID','IP'"])
```

Comment: What is not right with your code? Describe the problem you have.

Comment: `result` is your dictionary and those keys you're trying to access don't exist. Use the keys from the json object

Comment: `"'totalCount','ID','IP'"` is single key and you don't have this key in your dictionary.

Comment: This is the error I am getting : File "python", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes

First: you have to use double quotes `"` instead of `'` to have correctly formatted JSON.

Second: `"'totalCount','ID','IP'"` is single key and you don't have this key in dictionary

```
import json

example_string = '{"totalCount": "1", "ID": "1029", "IP": "10.0.0.1"}'
result = json.loads(example_string)

print('totalCount:', result['totalCount'])
print('ID:', result['ID'])
print('IP:', result['IP'])
```